# How to get fetched data to show on HTML

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I am going through the Coding Train video and trying my own take on it by fetching data from the [Poemist API](https://poemist.github.io/poemist-apidoc/). I can get the title of the poem from the API to show up in the console; however, I can't get it to display on the HTML (it just shows undefined). Anyone know what I might be doing wrong here? Below is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Fetch a poem</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Fetch a Poem</h1>
    <p id="poem">title</p>
    <script>
      console.log('about to fetch a poem');
      catchPoem()
        .then(poem => {
          document.getElementById('poem').innerText = poem;
          console.log('yay');
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('error!');
          console.error(error);
        });

      async function catchPoem() {
        const response = await fetch('https://www.poemist.com/api/v1/randompoems');
        let json = await response.json();
        let title = json[0].title
        console.log(title);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you return nothing in catchPoem, so you got undefined in then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async function catchPoem() {
    const response = await fetch('https://www.poemist.com/api/v1/randompoems');
    let json = await response.json();
    let title = json[0].title
    // console.log(title);
    return title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything from the function `catchPoem` that's why you're getting `undefined`. You just need to return `title` from the function.

```
if (title) {
    return title;
  }
```

```js
console.log('about to fetch a poem');

catchPoem()
  .then(poem => {
    document.getElementById('poem').innerText = poem;
    console.log('yay');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('error!');
    console.error(error);
  });

async function catchPoem() {
  const response = await fetch('https://www.poemist.com/api/v1/randompoems');
  let json = await response.json();
  let title = json[0].title
  console.log(title);
  if (title) {
    return title
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Fetch a Poem</h1>
<p id="poem">title</p>
```

Comment: catchPoem is async function, so no need to use Promise.resolve, just return result

Comment: how stupid I'm. I didn't see that. Thanks for the catch...